# Inserting values Into A column

Tags: sql, oracle

I know that this is the way to do it:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

But when I am trying to insert values into my table:

```
INSERT INTO harmeier
VALUES (23216,"Harmeier", "Cory", 45, '20130502');
```

It is saying column not allowed here.

here is table info:

```
STUDENT_ID  NUMBER(6,0) Yes  -   -
LAST_NAME   VARCHAR2(255)   Yes  -   -
FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(255)   Yes  -   -
CREDITS NUMBER(3,0) Yes  -   -
GRADUATION_DATE DATE    Yes  -   -
```

Comment: Please recite verbatim what "it is saying"

Comment: Google is awesome, just saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT  INTO harmeier
        (
          STUDENT_ID,
          LAST_NAME,
          FIRST_NAME,
          CREDITS,
          GRADUATION_DATE
        )
VALUES  (
          23216,
          'Harmeier',
          'Cory',
          45,
          to_date('20130502', 'yyyymmdd')
        );
```

Comment: Wow,, lol this is just not working for me, it is still stating literal values do not match string!!   :( frustrating

Comment: It's the date field.  You need to change '20130502' to:  to_date('20130502', 'yyyymmdd')

Comment: I edited my answer to give you the appropriate formatting for the date field.  I'm assuming by your error messages you're using an Oracle DB.

Comment: Sorry... I don't have easy access to an Oracle database to confirm this.  Can you just format the date properly?  Use '2013-05-02'

Comment: @Lawson - that will only work if the user's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `YYYY-MM-DD`, and by default it isn't. I'd recommend the ANSI date literal format `DATE '2013-05-02'` instead of `'2013-05-02'`.

Comment: can you reput the answer you just had up,, it looks like u edited it again with the to date statement

Answer (score 5):

Use single quotes:

```
INSERT
INTO    harmeier
VALUES  (23216, 'Harmeier', 'Cory', 45, '20130502');
```

Double quotes are used to delimit identifiers, not mark string constants.

Comment: It's also a good idea to specify the columns to put the data into, in the event the table structure is changed in the future.

Comment: INSERT
INTO    harmeier
VALUES  (23216, 'Harmeier', 'Cory', 45, '20130502');  This is giving me an error that states that literal values do not match format string

Comment: See my answer... you need to specify the column names.

Comment: @Lawson   I tried that:  INSERT INTO table_name (student_id    NUMBER(6),
    last_name VARCHAR2(255),
    first_name VARCHAR2(255),
    credits NUMBER(3),
    graduation_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE)
VALUES (23216, 'Harmeier', 'Cory', 45, '20130502'); And now It's giving me missing comma

Comment: No... use my answer below exactly.  Do not include "VARCHAR2(255)" or other data types... just the column name.